# SQL WITH clause execution order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I do my filtering, sorting and paging operations in stored procedures. The order of these operations should be in the execution order of **search->order->paging**. I don't know if my stored procedure does order by statements first or search operations first. So my questions are:

1) What is the execution order of this Stored Procedure?

2) If order by statements executes before search statements, how can I make search operations executes firstly?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Grid_Feedbacks_Select_All]
@search nvarchar(100),
@orderby nvarchar(50),
@orderbydirection nvarchar(4),
@skipLength int,
@length int
AS
BEGIN

--THIS PART IS ORDER BY PART
WITH CTE_Results
AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN (@orderby = 'Subject' AND @orderbydirection='asc')
                THEN Subject
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN (@orderby = 'Subject' AND @orderbydirection='desc')
               THEN Subject
    END DESC,

    CASE WHEN (@orderby = 'Text' AND @orderbydirection='asc')
              THEN Text
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 'Text' AND @orderbydirection='desc'
             THEN Text
    END DESC
) AS ROWNUM,

Count(*) over () AS TotalCount, 
(
    --THIS PART IS SEARCH PART
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Feedbacks f(nolock)) AS TotalRecordsCount,
    f.Id, 
    f.Response, 
    f.Subject, 
    f.Text, 
    u.Username, 
    c.FirmName, 
    c.Name, 
    c.Surname

    FROM Feedbacks f(nolock), Users u, Customers c 
    WHERE
    f.UserId = u.Id 
    AND u.CustomerId = c.Id
    OR(f.Text LIKE '%' + @search + '%')
    OR (u.Username LIKE '%' + @search + '%')
    OR (c.Name LIKE '%' + @search + '%')
)
--THIS PART IS PAGING PART
SELECT * FROM CTE_Results AS CPC
WHERE CPC.ROWNUM > @skipLength AND 
CPC.ROWNUM < @skipLength + @length + 1
ORDER BY CPC.ROWNUM ASC

END
```

Comment: Check the `Include Actual Execution Plan` option in your SSMS, run the query and check the execution plan yourself. Or if you can't make anything from it, post it for us to check. It' just guessing without looking at it.

Comment: And as for the guessing goes - it should be that searching (WHERE) is executed before sorting (ORDER BY)

Comment: Really you are worried the sort will be executed before the search.  How would you expect it to sort results it does not have.  With multiple UNIONS and multiple JOINS the query plan is effected by the order.  I even tune queries to get it to hit the the faster tables first.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "don't know, don't care".  SQL statements are descriptive.  They describe the output being produced.  SQL is *not* a procedure language, so the SQL engine is free to choose any execution order and optimization method that it likes.

The order of execution makes no difference whatsoever to the results.  The query plan is for returning all the results, not just a particular subset.

In other words, you are worrying about the wrong thing.  Just be sure the query is returning the data you want and written in the best way for the optimizer to take advantage of its abilities.

EDIT:

To be clear, the SQL Server [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clearly states:

> When SQL Server processes joins, the query engine chooses the most
>   efficient method (out of several possibilities) of processing the
>   join. The physical execution of various joins can use many different
>   optimizations and therefore cannot be reliably predicted.

When you have a large number of joins in a query (more than in the OP), the optimizer may not be able to consider all possibilities.  In that case, the join order *could* influence the query plan.  Much more important, though, are the statistics that the optimizer uses for choosing the ordering and types of join operations.  Microsoft has devoted a lot of effort to choosing the best execution plans.

Even so, in some cases, the optimizer might be wrong.  You can influence the results by using explicit query hints for joins.  I am not aware of any query hints that would apply to the OP question.  And, I don't think it is even worth considering unless there are current performance issues.

Comment: The order of the JOINS and order of the UNIONS can effect the query plan.  I often use the order in the TSQL to tune the execution plan.

Comment: Lets say I have 100000 feedback entries and 10 records include search text. Ordering 100000 records and then searching the text is the same as taking 10 records and then sorting that 10 records?? Can you explain how?

Comment: @Gordon And if DB engine has no optimizations for this kind of query then I have to change the query so that it will firstly take the records and then sort them.

Comment: @BerkArslan . . . A lot of effort goes into SQL optimizers to choose the best execution plan.  You can influence this with hints, but unless you are experiencing a particular performance problem, then let the compiler do its job.  It should be smart enough to do the right thing.

Comment: @Blam . . . Microsoft is pretty clear that the optimizer chooses a range of different execution plans for joins, even providing query and join hints to sidestep this optimization.  If you have counterexamples, I would be interested in learning more about them.  As for `union`s, I believe they are processed in the order they appear in the query, but I'm not aware of any formal documentation to that effect.  (And I note that the OP does not contain `union` so this is outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: It seemed to me that you generalized in the answer.  I have found that putting the UNIONS that return the least rows first is a faster.  I did not not vote you down.  It was just a comment.